# Identifying Cross-site scripting (XSS) attack inside a .docx file using react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, file-upload, xss, docx

I am writing a file upload component for .docx files and i want to identify xss attacks inside them. The approach i am using is reading the text from the file and matching the html tags that could be included inside the docx file.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import JSZip from 'jszip';

const DocxTextReader = () => {
  const [extractedText, setExtractedText] = useState('');

  const handleFileChange = async (event) => {
    const file = event.target.files[0];

    if (!file) {
      return;
    }

    try {
      const content = await readTextFromFile(file);
      setExtractedText(content);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error reading text:', error);
    }
  };

  const readTextFromFile = async (file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = async (event) => {
        const arrayBuffer = event.target.result;
        try {
          const content = await extractTextFromDocx(arrayBuffer);
          resolve(content);
        } catch (error) {
          reject(error);
        }
      };

      reader.onerror = (error) => {
        reject(error);
      };

      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    });
  };

  const extractTextFromDocx = async (arrayBuffer) => {
    const zip = new JSZip();

    try {
      const docxZip = await zip.loadAsync(arrayBuffer);
      const contentXml = await docxZip
        .file('word/document.xml')
        .async('string');
      const text = parseTextFromXml(contentXml);
      return text;
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error('Error extracting text from docx:', error);
    }
  };

  const parseTextFromXml = (xml) => {
    const textRegex = /<w:t.*?>(.*?)<\/w:t>/g;
    const textMatches = xml.match(textRegex);

    if (!textMatches) {
      throw new Error('No text found in document');
    }

    const extractedText = textMatches
      .map((match) => {
        const text = match.replace(/<\/?w:t.*?>/g, '');
        return text;
      })
      .join(' ');

    // Words or patterns to detect
    const forbiddenWords = [
      '<script>',
      'alert(',
      'onmouseover',
      'dangerouslySetInnerHTML',
      '<a href=>',
    ];

    // Check for forbidden words or patterns
    const hasForbiddenWords = forbiddenWords.some((word) =>
      extractedText.includes(word)
    );

    if (hasForbiddenWords) {
      console.warn(
        'Warning: Extracted text contains forbidden words or patterns.'
      );
    }

    return extractedText;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="file" onChange={handleFileChange} />
      <div>
        <pre>{extractedText}</pre>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DocxTextReader;
```

I am using `jszip` package and i am also aware that there is `mammoth.js` which also can be used here. But due to the licensing conditions i can only use MIT licenced libraries and i would like to know if there are any alternative MIT licensed libraries for that.
And i also want to know that if i can avoid xss attacks by mentioning all the available html tags inside `forbiddenWords` array or is there a better approach for this using react and typescript.